# Parse multicast RTP url

Tags: java, android

I have the below multicast RTP url.

```
rtp://10.70.220.50@232.24.0.170:5001
```

How can i parse the below using java

```
source ip(10.7.220.50)
multicast ip (232.24.0.170)
Port (5001)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `"rtp://10.70.220.50@232.24.0.170:5001"` fits the model of a *hierarchical* URI with a *server-based authority* and no *path*, *query* or *fragment* component.  So you should be able to parse it as follows using the standard `URI` class:

```
  // Parse ...
  URI uri = new URI("rtp://10.70.220.50@232.24.0.170:5001");

  String protocol = uri.getProtocol();  // "rtp"
  String sourceIp = uri.getUserInfo();  // "10.70.220.50"
  String multicastIP = uri.getHost();   // "232.24.0.170"
  int port = uri.getPort();             // 5001
```

Note that the `sourceIP` won't be checked to ensure it is an IP address.

Refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) for `java.net.URI` for more details ... including an explanation of the standard terminology I used above.